# PHP exec does not return a string on specific programs

Tags: php, c

if i execute this command in the shell, i can see the return string.  however, `exec()` is not returning anything.  i've also tried `shell_exec()` to no avail.  safe mode is turned off in php.ini.  the permissions on the executable are `rwxr-x-r-x`.  i've tried using the full path and the short path.  i can execute `ls` with no problems, and it returns the appropriate data but i cannot get the output from this c program i've written for some reason.  it prints to `stdout` using the `printf()` function, and, again, prints to the command line without issue, but php won't pick it up.  what gives?

`$string_array;

exec("/bin/weight",$string_array);

var_dump($string_array);`

replacing `"/bin/weight"` with `"/bin/ls"` shows a proper result.  when i execute `"/bin/weight"` in a shell, it prints `{motion=false,weight=0,uom="LBS"}` as it is supposed to, but it somehow does not make it to php.  again, in `php.ini`, `safe_mode = Off`.  pulling my hair out here...

important bits of the c program:

```
//build return string and send back to stdout
char weight_buf[32];
char result[1024]="{motion=";

if(motion==FALSE) {
        strcat(result, "false,");
} else {
        strcat(result, "true,");
}
strcat(result, "weight=");
if(negative==TRUE) {
        strcat(result, "-");
}
//itoa(weight, weight_buf, 10);
sprintf(result, "%s%d", result, weight);
strcat(result, weight_buf);
strcat(result, ",uom=\"");
strcat(result, "LBS");  //TODO: fill in the actual units here
strcat(result, "\"}");
printf("%s\n", result);

return 0;
```

the above code prints to `stdout` just fine when executed from a command line:

Comment: What's your code look like (c and php)

Comment: Is the C program actually being run when you run it from PHP? Make it write to a file or something and make sure it's actually outputting what you expect it to. Also look at PHP errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL) ; ini_set('display_errors', 1); `

Comment: updated with more code and proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have it figured out.  this c program opens a serial port and it appears that php is failing to open it.  it is probably a permissions issue on the serial port, but maybe something else.  the offending code is here:

```
int fd;
char buf[14];
int res=0;

//printf("opening port...%s", "\n");
fd=open("/dev/pts/0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);

if(fd==-1) {
        //printf("unable to open serial port%s", "\n");
        return -2;
} else {
        //port was successfully opened, set termios vars
        ...
```

i was able to figure this out by adding a `return_var` argument to the `exec()` command like so:

```
$string_array;
exec("/bin/weight",$string_array,$return_code);
var_dump($string_array);
print($return_code);
```

`'254'` (basically `-2`) was returned, meaning the port failed to open.  thanks to all who attempted to help with this.

simply changing the permissions on `/dev/pts/0` to `666` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

From [exec manual page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument,
> then the return status of the executed command will be written to this
> variable.

What you are looking for, in order to print stdout, is [system()](https://www.php.net/system) or [passthru()](https://www.php.net/passthru)

To clarify, you can pass a variable into exec() that will receive all the output, but it is not returned by this function, only the return code of the script.

Comment: string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

Comment: If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

Answer (score 1):

Going by the question title, this is only a problem for some programs.

This behaviour can be explained by programs writing to stderr instead of stdout. To cater for this, you need to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
exec("/bin/weight 2>&1",$string_array);
```

Comment: i'm guessing this just prints both `stdout` and `stderr` to `stdout`?  no dice, though.  the array is still empty.  :(

Comment: @moonlightcheese Anything in your PHP error log? Have you run the PHP script by hand, or just through a browser (this may be a security related issue with file permissions, so `ls -l /bin/weight` would be good)

Comment: it seems to be a permissions issue, but not on the program itself.  the program opens a serial port and it seems to be failing on the open.  i guess i'll have to give apache/php permissions on that `/dev` entry or something.  will probably post another question regarding access privs for apache/php.